# Keras multi-class model with wrong dimensions

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

New to Keras, trying to reimplement this following binary image classification example from: https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

It works for binary classification for me. 
Rebuilding it for a 3-class classification I am getting the following dimensions mismatch error:

```
     60         epochs=50,
     61         validation_data=validation_generator,
---> 62         validation_steps=250 // batch_size)
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_50 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (16, 3)
```

This is my current implementation:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
batch_size = 16

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# this is a generator that will read pictures found in
# subfolers of 'data/train', and indefinitely generate
# batches of augmented image data
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'F://train_data//',  # this is the target directory
        target_size=(150, 150),  # all images will be resized to 150x150
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical')  # since we use binary_crossentropy loss, we need binary labels

# this is a similar generator, for validation data
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'F://validation_data//',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical')

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3, 150, 150)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_first"))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_first"))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_first"))

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('softmax')) # instead of sigmoid

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# another loss: sparse_categorical_crossentropy

model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=1800 // batch_size,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=250 // batch_size)
```

So far I have changed the activation function of the output layer from *sigmoid* to *softmax*. Changed class_mode from *binary* to *categorical*. Can't seem to find the problem.

Also, I am aware of similar questions on StackOverflow: 
[Multi-Output Multi-Class Keras Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708506/multi-output-multi-class-keras-model)

[Train multi-class image classifier in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823068/train-multi-class-image-classifier-in-keras)

[Multi-class classification using keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42873166/multi-class-classification-using-keras)

But none of the solutions helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the final `Dense` layer to `model.add(Dense(3))`. Softmax activation expects the `units` in the `Dense` layer to match the number of classes.

Also, if you are going to use `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'`, remember to change `class_mode` into `'sparse'`. Your current setting, `class_mode='categorical'`, should be used with `loss='categorical_crossentropy'`.